# Exception with System.arraycopy in Java

Tags: java, methods, arrays

I've been having trouble with this method class. I used System.arraycopy but admittedly how it works 100%. I've been getting this error when trying to test it:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at fenn19.GenericStack.push(GenericStack.java:31)
    at fenn19.Test.main(Test.java:8)
```

Line 31:

```
System.arraycopy(list, 0, o, 0, list.length);
```

The method class:

```
public class GenericStack<E> {
    public static int size = 16;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private E[] list = (E[])new Object[size];

  public void add(int index, E e) {
      ensureCapacity();

      for (int i = size - 1; i >= index; i--) {
          list[i + 1] = list[i];

      list[index] = e;

      size++;   
    }
  }
  public int getLength() {
    return list.length;
  }

  public E peek() {
      E o = null;
      for (int i = 0; i > list.length; i++) {
          o = list[i - 1];
    }
      return o;
  }
  public E push(E o) {
        System.arraycopy(list, 0, o, 0, list.length);
        size++;
        return o;
  }
  public E pop() {
      E o = null;
      for (int i = 0; i > list.length; i++) {
          o = list[i - 1];
    }
        list[list.length - 1] = null;
        size--;
        return o;
      }
  private void ensureCapacity() {
      if (size >= list.length) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        E[] newlist = (E[])(new Object[size * 2 + 1]);
          System.arraycopy(list, 0, newlist, 0, size);
          list = newlist;
      }
  }
  public boolean isEmpty() {
      if (list.length < 0) {
        return false;
      }
      else {
          return true;
      }
   }
}
```

The test class:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
    GenericStack<String> est = new GenericStack<String>();

    est.push("Washington DC");
    est.push("Paris");
    est.push("Ottawa");
    est.push("London");
    est.push("Tampa");

    System.out.println(est);
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.arraycopy` copies from one array to another.  You're passing it an instance of `E`  as the target array in your push method, but you've defined the type in your test class as `String`.  `String` is not a type of array, so you can't copy things to it using `System.arraycopy`.

Comment: I understand what you're saying but I still don't know how to fix the problem.

Comment: I've expanded my comment into an answer that includes advice on proper implementation.

Comment: @dungo I also advise looking at the source code for `java.util.ArrayList`. You can learn a huge amount from it.

Comment: Don't use arrays - they are for JDK devs: Use a `List<E>` instead - the Collections API is for application devs.

Comment: @Bohemian Shouldn't an application dev just use a `Deque<E>` instead of writing their own stack? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the API for [`System.arraycopy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-), you'll see that it's a method that copies data from one array to another array.

When you invoke it in your `push` method, you're handing it an instance of `E` as the target array.

However, in your `Test` class you've created a `GenericStack<String>`.  Since a `String` is not a type of array, when you attempt to copy data into it you get an error.

What you really should be doing in your `push` method is first checking to see if you have more room in your existing array.  If so, just add the new element and increment the size.

If your backing array is full, create a new (larger) array, copy the current backing array into it, and then add the element to the new array.